# JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode' in React functional HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, high-order-component

I need to write HOC that will wrap my components into Suspense, I will pass the component and fallback as HOC props.

my hoc:

```
export const withSuspense = ({ Component, Fallback }: any)=> {

  return (props:any) => {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Fallback />}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Suspense>
    );
  };
};
```

Then I need to render in a Route(react-router v 6.15)

```
  <Route
    path="messages"
    element={withSuspense({MessagesPage,Loader})}
  />
```

Got an error **Type '(props: any) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'**.

I tried to define the HOC props as ReactNodes but it didn't work. Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 'JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode' in React functional HOC

`element` in the newest `react-router-dom` expects a `ReactNode`, not a function, that returns `JSX` or `ReactNode`.

```
const Component = withSuspense({ MessagesPage, Loader });

<Route
  path="messages"
  element={<Component />}
/>
```